# View JSON content in tkInter window with a vertical scrollbar

Tags: python, json, tkinter

I want to see my parsed JSON in a tkInter window using a pretty format. If the JSON content is more, its not visible.

I went through one snippet but all the data is displayed in a single line and without slide bar.

```
myWin = Tk()
label1 = Label(myWin, text=json.dumps(sg_details_json), font="Times32")
label1.pack()
myWin.mainloop()
```

Expected result:

```
{
    name: "John", 
    age: 31, 
    city: "New York"
}
```

Actual result:

```
{name: "John", age: 31, city: "New York"}
```

Comment: first you have to format it - ie. `json.dumps(data, indent=2)`, next you would have to align text in label.

Comment: Wohoo!!! Its working now... yippeee!
with open('sgrules', "r") as f:
    data = json.load(f)

text = json.dumps(data, indent=2)

Comment: @furas you are my man... Now, I have more critical tasks to do to integrate this in the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to format string with JSON. You can use `indent=` for this

```
import tkinter as tk
import json

data = {'name': "John", 'age': 31, 'city': "New York"}
text = json.dumps(data, indent=2)

root = tk.Tk()

lbl = tk.Label(root, text=text, font="Times32")
lbl.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Now you have to align/justify text in widget - `Label(..., justify='left')`

```
import tkinter as tk
import json

data = {'name': "John", 'age': 31, 'city': "New York"}
text = json.dumps(data, indent=2)

root = tk.Tk()

lbl = tk.Label(root, text=text, font="Times32", justify='left')
lbl.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Or use `Text` instead of `Label`

```
import tkinter as tk
import json

data = {'name': "John", 'age': 31, 'city': "New York"}
text = json.dumps(data, indent=2)

root = tk.Tk()

txt = tk.Text(root, font="Times32")
txt.pack()
txt.insert('end', text)

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

`Text` can work with `Scrollbar`, and `Label` can't do this.

```
import tkinter as tk
import json

data = {'name': "John", 'age': 31, 'city': "New York"}
text = json.dumps(data, indent=2)

root = tk.Tk()

sb = tk.Scrollbar(root)
sb.pack(side='right', fill='y')

txt = tk.Text(root, font="Times32")
txt.pack()

txt.config(yscrollcommand=sb.set)
sb.config(command=txt.yview)

txt.insert('end', text)
txt.insert('end', text) # add again to get longer text in Widget
txt.insert('end', text) # add again to get longer text in Widget
txt.insert('end', text) # add again to get longer text in Widget
txt.insert('end', text) # add again to get longer text in Widget

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
from tkinter import *
```

For `import`.

```
def text():
    global string
    with open(sg_details_json, 'r') as r:
        data = json.load(r)
        dataname = data['name'] # To get a single variable
        dataage = data['age']
        datacity = data['city']
```

Then for getting data separately.

```
        string = '%s\n%s\n%s' % (dataname, dataage, datacity)
```

And adding each of the *dict* object to new lines(using `\n`).

```
myWin = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(myWin, bg='black')
canvas.pack(side=LEFT)
scrollbar = Scrollbar(myWin, command=canvas.yview, bg='black')
scrollbar.pack(side=LEFT, fill='y', anchor='e', expand=True)
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
def on_configure(event):
    canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox('all'))
canvas.bind('<Configure>', on_configure)
frame = Frame(myWin, bg='black')
canvas.create_window((20, 20), window=frame, anchor='nw')
label1 = Label(frame, text=string, font="Times32")
label1.pack()
myWin.mainloop()
```

Then adding them to a `Frame` inside of a `Scrollbar` inside of a `Canvas`.

Comment: you could write description in answer.

Comment: If JSON in too large say, 22k arrays and then elements in single array around 20-30 in number. I don't think if its required to get them in a dict everytime. Is it necessary?